# How to wrap C pointer in Go without triggering "cgo result has Go pointer"

Tags: python, c, pointers, go

I am trying to implement a function in cgo that wraps a `double` array in a `Slice`:

```
//export ArrayToSlice
func ArrayToSlice(a *C.double, length int) (*[]float64) {
    hdr := reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data: uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(a)),
        Len:  length,
        Cap:  length,
    }
    return (*[]float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&hdr))
}
```

this function is supposed to be [called from C, return the Slice to C, which will then pass it to another Go function](https://github.com/nils-werner/python-go-cffi/blob/master/py/gosum.py#L15).

This used to work with Go 1.5, but with 1.6 it started showing this panic:

```
panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer
```

I understand what the issue is: Go does not want to hand out its pointers to C, because Go is garbage collected and might destroy pointers that are in the hands of the non-garbage collected C code.

Is there a way to do this in Go 1.6?

Comment: The error says "cgo result has Go pointer" because the return value from `ArrayToSlice` is a Go pointer